# Google Cloud Storage vs Google Cloud CDN

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I have several video content that I share through my Google Cloud Storage through my Django Google App Engine Application with signed url mechanism associated with an expiration time.

```
def get_signed_url(self, entity):
    blob = bucket.get_blob(entity.url)
    logging.info(entity.url)
    expiration_time = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=120)
    signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration_time)
    logging.info(signed_url)

    return signed_url
```

Although it has been explained in [here][1] possible usage relationship of GCS and Google Cloud CDN, would this be applicable to stream video content (MP4 or MPEG-DASH with MP4) through Google Cloud Storage as it is mentioned to have an implicit CDN itself.

If using Google CDN is a wiser way to broadcast online video content, what would be the best strategy to achieve this, how can I use the Google Cloud CDN on top of my current implementation with Google Cloud Storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question of **how can I use the Google Cloud CDN on top of my current implementation with Google Cloud Storage** on your django. You can base your **implementation** below with **django-storages**

**requirements.txt** (the versions are the latest up to this day: **05-31-2020**)

```
...
django-storages==1.19.1
google-cloud-storage==1.28.1
```

**example/example/settings.py**

```
...
...
SB_SA_FILE = os.environ.get('STORAGE_BUCKETS_FILE',
                            'storageBucketsBackendServiceKey.json')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'example.lib.storages.GoogleStaticFilesStorage'  # static
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'example.lib.storages.GoogleMediaFilesStorage'  # media
GS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'publicRead'
GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    f'/usr/src/app/{SB_SA_FILE}'
)
GS_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('GS_BUCKET_NAME')
CDN_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get('CDN_HOSTNAME', '')
```

**example/example/lib/storages.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage



class GoogleMediaFilesStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):

    def _save(self, name, content):
        name = f'{settings.MEDIA_URL[1:]}{name}'
        return super()._save(name, content)

    def url(self, name):
        """
        @brief      for implementation of CDN using image field url
        @return     Dynamic return of CDN or local URL
        """
        if settings.CDN_HOSTNAME:
            url = f'{settings.CDN_HOSTNAME}/{name}'
            return url
        return super().url(name)


class GoogleStaticFilesStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
    def url(self, name):
        name = f'static/{name}'
        if settings.CDN_HOSTNAME:
            url = f'{settings.CDN_HOSTNAME}/{name}'
            return url
        return super().url(name)
```

**Lastly**, you need to run your django application with a `CDN_HOSTNAME` environment variable. The value of `CDN_HOSTNAME` environment variable must be the domain mapped in your Google Cloud Global Load Balancer which your desired Cloud Storage is set as a backend bucket

Comment: Thanks Dean, that is greatly appreciated.  What about using signed urls and access restrictions ? How can I use them Google CDN ?

Comment: Hi @SuperEye, I have never tried using signedURLs.. But according to the documentation here: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html

You just need to remove `GS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'publicRead'`

Comment: But, this does not provide a mechanism to restrict access to certain files. To achieve this, signed_url mechanism should be employed.

Comment: Oh.. Particular files only.. So yes, I guess you are correct.. You may need to put some logic on your django application for your case

Comment: Hi @Dean, and as far as I can see, in your suggestion whole data will pass through the application here. I am looking for a way which the user will directly communicate to the Storage/CDN not via the application, where it will have Google storage as origin, Google CDN as CDN while having restiricted access via signed urls.

Comment: It should communicate directly through the Storage/CDN. Let us say you have an API that returns images. The Image URL that will be passed on the client let us say a browser will be your URL of image hosted in either your Storge/CDN

Answer (score 18):

Although Google Cloud Storage leverage "parts" of the CDN infrastructure, it is only a convenience layer, with no control over cache keys, invalidation and requires either a public bucket (at odds with signed URLs), or per-object Cache-Control metadata to be set.

Egressing large volumes of data (e.g. HLS/DASH video) from a bucket is also a fair bit more expensive - for North America, it ranges from $0.12 - $0.08 based on volume. Cloud CDN ranges from $0.08 - $0.02 (after a petabyte) for North America egress.

You should also take a look at the [Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/private-content) support in Cloud CDN, which allows you protect your video segments from unauthorized access on a per-user basis - similar to GCS signed URLs.

**TL;DR:** GCS & its caching mode are a nice convenience and good for small traffic volumes, but if you plan to even serve a few hundred GB (let alone more), setting up a HTTPS Load Balancer + Cloud CDN in front of a bucket will give you a lot more flexibility and reduced costs.

(I am the PM for Cloud CDN, if it helps!)

Comment: you mean to say  " setting up a HTTPS Load Balancer + Cloud CDN in front of a bucket"  you mean to say in front of Object store bucket?..